# Centering the titlebar in Android using an activity

Tags: android, class, android-activity, centering, titlebar

So I am trying to center my applications title using the first activity.java class that one starts out with.

Here is my code

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   -----setTitle(R.string.app_name1); //Sets the title for this activity using the app_name1 string
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

So the line with the "-----" is my code for my title(Of course there not in my real code just on this question). I am using the string app_name to pull the title from so how exactly would I be able to center it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Centering Title bar at Center you can create custom title bar as:

```
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,
R.layout.title_bar);
```

**title_bar.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linear" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/centertxt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="title bar"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20sp"
       />
    </RelativeLayout >
```

Comment: I don't get what this does   getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,
R.layout.title_bar); and are you saying to use one or the other? Either the title_bar.xml one or the one I just specified? It be really great if you could explain more.

Comment: no i'm not saying use one more title bar.i mean use custom  title bar instead of system default title bar. when you are creating custom title bar it require an xml layout as second parameter.in this layout you are able to align your text as you want in center,right or left...

Comment: for title_bar.xml add new xml file in your res/layout folder and put your xml for title bar.i you have any problem then ask me

Comment: Ah I can't get it to work if you could could you teamviewer me?

Comment: I downloaded it put it on 2.3.3 and it had one error and I fixed it by taking out the @override. Then I ran it. But the title at the very top (The little gray bar) was not centered. And that's what I'm trying to center.

Comment: why you are saying it's not working it's working perfectly on android2.3.3

Comment: download from here working for android 2.3.3 https://sites.google.com/site/imrankhanandroid/Customtiitleee.rar?attredirects=0&d=1